# Windows Batch File to Move files based on part of filename, to different folders

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I have some files in C:\Test\All_PDF folder. I want to move these file to separate folders in C:\Test based on a first part of the file name. Folders are already created.

For an example my file names are like:

```
 1234-TEST-FileOne.pdf

 5678-TEST-FileTwo.pdf
```

And the folder names are like

```
 1234

 5678
```

So I need a batch file which looks for the first part of the file name (until the first - of the file name) and move it to the receptive folders.

I would really appreciate if someone could help.

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
SET "sourcedir=C:/Test/All_PDF"
SET "destdir=C:/Test"
FOR /f "delims=" %%a IN ( 'dir /b /a-d "%sourcedir%*.pdf" ' ) DO (
    FOR /f "tokens=1delims=-" %%b IN ("%%a") DO (
        FOR /f "delims=" %%d IN ( 'dir /b /ad "%destdir%*%%b*" ' ) DO (
            (MOVE "%%a" "%destdir%\%%d\"
        )
    )
)
GOTO :EOF
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I am very new to batch files. But I have used something like below.      
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
SET "sourcedir=C:/Test/All_PDF"
SET "destdir=C:/Test"
FOR /f "delims=" %%a IN (
 'dir /b /a-d "%sourcedir%\*.pdf" '
 ) DO (
 FOR /f "tokens=1delims=-" %%b IN ("%%a") DO (
  FOR /f "delims=" %%d IN (
  'dir /b /ad "%destdir%\*%%b*" '
  ) DO (
   (MOVE "%%a" "%destdir%\%%d\"
  )
 )
)

GOTO :EOF

Comment: I have edited your question to include the code from your comment. You can now delete the comment. Please take a look at the code, check that it looks the same as when you tested it. There is an obvious imbalance in your parentheses, you should remove the opening parenthesis immediately before `MOVE`. You should also replace the `/`'s on lines `3` & `4` with `\ `'s, and add the missing separators on lines `5` and `7` too.

Comment: Thank you! I will modify the code and try